# Error con angular material en Angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15

Cuando intento utilizar cualquier elemento de angular material me aparece este error:

> NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Todo mi proyecto está en el siguiente repositorio:
[Proyecto semáforo](https://github.com/giselle-gh/Red-Light-Green-Light-Project.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola revise tu repo y no estas importando Material al Proyecto, lo mas usual es crear un Modulo de Material y ese modulo importarlo en App.Module.

te dejo un `app.module.ts   & material.module.ts` de ejemplo de como se ve con importaciones de componentes de Angular Material

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from 
'@angular/forms';

 import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

 import {
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRippleModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from 
'@angular/platformbrowser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { YahooService } from './yahoo.service';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
     MatButtonModule,
     MatFormFieldModule,
     MatInputModule,
     MatRippleModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    SearchComponent,
  ],
})

export class MaterialModule {};
```

App.module:

```
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
     ],
    imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       **MaterialModule**,
       FormsModule,
       HttpModule,
       HttpClientModule,
     ],
     providers: [
         YahooService,
     ],
     Bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
     ],
     schemas: [
        **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA**,
     ],
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Te recomiendo profundizar en teams de modularizacion, exports e Imports de Anguar. https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/angularya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=14&codigo=14&inicio=0